# $ \begin{vmatrix} f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\ f(b) & g(b) & h(b) \\ f'(c) & g'(c) & h'(c) \\ \end{vmatrix} =0 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

If $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ have derivatives in $[a,b]$, show that there exists a value $c$ of $x$ in $(a,b)$ such that $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\
    f(b) & g(b) & h(b) \\
    f'(c) & g'(c) & h'(c) \\
    \end{vmatrix} =0
$$

I am getting an idea of using generalized mean value theorem, but not able to proceed. Need help!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Generalization_for_determinants)

Comment: The functions are assumed to be at least $C^1$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let 
$$
F(x) = \det 
\begin{bmatrix} 
f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\ f(b)& g(b) & h(b) \\ f(x) & g(x) & h(x)
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $F(a) = F(b )=0$. Also note that
$$
F'(x) = \det
\begin{bmatrix} 
f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\ f(b)& g(b) & h(b) \\ f'(x) & g'(x) & h'(x)
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which could be directly showed by definition of derivatives.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the function

$$j(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
    f(a) & g(a) & h(a) \\
    f(b) & g(b) & h(b) \\
    f(x) & g(x) & h(x) \\
    \end{vmatrix}.$$

Note that (assuming all functions are differentiable and thus continuous), $j$ is a continuous function with $j(a)=j(b)=0$...